# Convert XML data into a table SQL, Different tag in one script

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have one XML data which I want to bring them into a one table
the XML data is like this:

```
<return>
<start>
  <name>Sara</name>
  <familyname>Moradi</familyname>
  <age>22</age>
</start>
<start>
  <name>Sam</name>
  <familyname>Mic</familyname>
  <age>32</age>
</start>
<errorCode>0</errorCode>
<resultStatus/>
<extra>22255</extra>
</return>
```

and I wanna create a table like this:

| name | familyname | age | errorCode | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sara | Moradi | 22 | 0 | 22255 |
| Sam | Mic | 32 | 0 | 22255 |

I check the previous ones but they didn't help me.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the error, problem? Please edit the question and show your code.

Comment: the second part which is start from <errorCode> I can't bring it to my output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Try below:

declare @data xml = convert(xml, '<return>
    <start>
      <name>Sara</name>
      <familyname>Moradi</familyname>
      <age>22</age>
    </start>
    <start>
      <name>Sam</name>
      <familyname>Mic</familyname>
      <age>32</age>
    </start>
    <errorCode>0</errorCode>
    <resultStatus/>
    <extra>22255</extra>
    </return>')
    
    SELECT X.Y.value('(name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') as name,
           X.Y.value('(familyname)[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')   as familyname,
           X.Y.value('(age)[1]', 'int') as age,
           A.B.value('(errorCode)[1]','int') as errorCode,
           A.B.value('(extra)[1]','int') as extra
    FROM  @data.nodes('return') as A(B)
    cross apply A.B.nodes('start') as X(Y)
```

For quick solution, I have stored xml data into variable, you need to  replace it with your original column from table.

Comment: what is [1] in front of columns name?

Comment: It identifies which node value to retrieve if there are multiple node with same name inside the parent node. As a standard format, there will be always 1  unique child node under parent node. So it will always get the first node values once it finds under parent node.